# How to set header and footer in libreoffice outside the border

Tags: 13.04, libreoffice

I am using libreoffice for creating documents in 13.04 , but I can't move header and footer outside border, Is there any to do it?

Comment: Did any of the answers solve your issue? If not, please comment what doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can't move the header / footer beyond the page margins. When setting up the page layout, the header / footer will always stay inside the page margins. The spacing between header / footer and main page content is set on the header / footer properties tab of the page's properties dialogue.

So:

- to increase the space between header and the top of the main content area, you need to increase the spacing value on the `Header` tab of the `Page Style` dialogue (Menu `Format` -> `Page`).
- to keep the top border of the main content area and to "move" the header upwards, you need to modify two values: **decrease the page's top margin**, and **increase the spacing between header and main content** ***by the same value***.

For a visual description how the different page/header/footer properties affect the page layout, see [my answer on superuser](https://superuser.com/a/642914/84724).

Answer (score 0):

Double click near the top of the page to show the header, and then drag the header slider up, and may have to drag the page slider down, and that will put the header, and footer outside the boarder (Notice the border in the images).  Keep in mind that it might make it smaller.  See images below.

This was done with LO 4.0, and Ubuntu 13.04.

[image]

[image]

Comment: But it is still inside the border

Comment: Just barely, I think that is the best that you're going to get.  Sorry that its not perfect:)

Comment: What you can try is to reduce the size of the border just a bit, and see if works for you.

Comment: I've found it's [easier to adjust the numbers manually, as tohuwawohu suggests](http://askubuntu.com/a/356676/22949), to get the margins set at exactly the right value.

Answer (score 0):

You need untick in box "**Surround header**" and "**footer**" (**Border and Shading Options**)

Comment: I cannot find *Border and Shading Options* in LibreOffice. This seems to be present in Microsoft Word, but is it in LibreOffice Writer? If so, can you tell us where?